# How to generate automatic email including attachment with SMTP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, automation, smtp

I want to send the Email at particular date with attachments. How to generate the automatic mail with the attachment.

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. See "[What Have You Tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)" for an excellent article that you _really need to read_.

Answer (score 0):

Start here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx

Lots of information including examples.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want an automated email you will need something that will triger it. you can either create a console application to send an email (Please refer to the URL mentioned by John to write code to send email) and then use task scheduler and schedule the console application.

Or you can  write a windows service to send an email. this is little complicated than the console application approach.